# Sort Map with respect to order of keys in second map

Tags: java

I've 2 `LinkedHashMaps<String, SomeList>,` say **Map1**, **Map2** The keys in both the maps are same but orders can be different.

Example:

**Map1:**

```
Hello, Value1
How, Value2
Are, Value3
You, Value4
```

**Map2:**

```
Hello, Value1
You, Value4
Are, Value3
How, Value2
```

I want to sort the Map2 by keys such that its order then becomes same as Map1.

Result I'm looking for:

**Map2:**

```
Hello, Value1
How, Value2
Are, Value3
You, Value4
```

Comment: You can't sort a `LinkedHashMap` you could iterate over `map1` and create a new `Map` with the insertion order of `map1`, but that still doesn't count as **sorted**

Answer (score 3):

Just create a new `LinkedHashMap` by iterating over the keys of `map1` and obtaining for each key the corresponding value of `map2`:

```
Map<String,String> sorted =
    map1.keySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                                  map2::get,
                                  (v1,v2)->v1,
                                  LinkedHashMap::new));
```